# Action on Google Smart Home using AWS lambda in Python

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I wrote a smart home skill for Alexa using AWS lambda and Python. That's working all good.

Now I have moved on to Action on Google and I want to build the Skill on AWS lambda I used AWS API Gateway created a post call and gave the URL in the Fulfillment Tab of Action on Google. Now I wanted to check if the connection has been established between AWS lambda and Action on Google. I am pretty confused about how to check this?

Second Thing I am wondering does Action on Google Support Python because there are no examples in python nor anyone in the community has used python.

On there Github Repo they have given the code in NodeJS I wanted to understand the working by performing the Simulation First But it's not helping much. Like I wanted to understand the flow from the basics like When I developed for Alexa I started with Authorization and then moved on to the Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you locked in on using Python in your stack? If you're flexible and can switch to NodeJS, you can use Actions on Google's NodeJS client library to connect with AWS Lambda.

Docs here: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview#example_aws_lambda_api_gateway

Comment: I am comfortable in switching to Nodejs for AWS lambda but there's no sample template for that too. I saw the document you shared and I'm a beginner that's why it's not making that much sense to me. I'm searching for something which can give me a brief idea about how should I implement it. Like a reference or starter template so that I can start development without any complexity. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! 

Google has put together a few Codelabs aimed at helping beginners understand the developer experience for Actions on Google and Dialogflow. 

They should help you with references and starter templates:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-2/#0

Comment: Thanks it helped me lot.